# Linea Pro Scanner implementation using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have scanned the barcode using ZBar SDK which scans barcode by opening camera. It's working nice but now I want to scan the barcode using Linea Pro SDK. Can anyone please help me to do this with xcode ?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://github.com/iampnelson/LineaPro-TiModule

Comment: Ya. i have downloaded the folder and in lineaiphone3.0.zip i found liblinea.a file that i have added in my xcode project. Now i am confused what i have to do next?

Comment: Try to have a look at the example named "LineaPRO_Module_Ti_3.0_iOS_6.0_Example" that is provided in above URL you downloaded, you will have to understand how to implement it, try to run the project and find what you all need to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the sdk from "http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/Linea-Pro-iPhone-SDK/8/102" and it's providing LineaDemo also. I have run the application and it scanned the barcode perfectly.